# How do I mass click on a link to save time?

Tags: gmail, links, google-chrome-extensions

I know of linkclump, but it doesn't work on the "remove" link as shown in this gmail screenshot. I hate having to individually click on each "remove" link. What's a way to solve this problem?

[image: Gmail screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JavaScript to do that. Open up your browser's console and paste this (jQuery): http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

Then this:

```
$('.alP').each(function () { if($(this).html() === 'remove') $(this).click() })
```

when the labels page is opened. You could save this as a [bookmarkarklet](http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) if you need to remove labels often.

Comment: apologies, could you break this down more step by step? How do I open the browser's console? Where exactly do I paste the link (is it the link I should be pasting)? Where do I paste the code you provided?

Comment: I don't know which webbrowser you use. Google 'open browser console <name of your webbrowser>'. Don't paste the link. Paste the contents of the link.